# ckeditor Rails 4 carrierwave s3 fog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, ckeditor, carrierwave, fog

I am having a lot of difficulties uploading images to S3 via CarrierWave & Fog. I already had set up carrierwave and s3 and had no problems but then I added Ckeditor. The biggest problem I am having is that all the images I upload using the Ckeditor photouploader have an expiration time. I don't want them to expire and I can't find any documentation on how to change this.

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|

  config.root = Rails.root.join('tmp') # adding these...
  config.cache_dir = 'carrierwave' # ...two lines


  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',                        # required
    :aws_access_key_id      => ENV['AWS_KEY'],                        # required
    :aws_secret_access_key  => ENV['AWS_SECRET'],                        # required
    :region                 => ENV['AWS_REGION'],                  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
  }
  config.fog_directory  = ENV['FOG_DIR']                          # required
  config.fog_public     = false                                       # optional, defaults to true
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>"max-age=#{365.day.to_i}"} # optional, defaults to {}
end
```

So I have solved the fact that `config.fog_public` needs to be set to `true` on s3 to receive urls without expiration dates. Does anyone know how to change a lot of images that are on s3 with expiration dates to public without having to reupload all of the images?

Comment: Okay well I have figured out that using config.fog_public = false means that you have to get private links. Now I have another question: I have uploaded a lot of images to S3 that are private and I want to make them public. Is that possible?

Comment: I figured it out! You can go to S3 portal and click on a folder then click the "Actions" dropdown button then click "Make Public"

Comment: Glad to here you were able to resolve this. Thanks for sharing your findings!